# Codeigniter 3 - sess_time_to_update AND sess_save_path

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

So - I look in my '**sess_save_path**' folder and I find **over 1000 ci_sesson files**

- Is this necessary for a site that has maybe 3 people logging in every day?
- How can I - or should I even try to - reduce the number of these being set?

What is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it's PHP decision of delete or not the file.

So to get rid of those files more often, I had to add the following code onbeggining of `config.php`

```
if(!headers_sent()){
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
}
```

This define a chance of 1% (1/100) to GC delete session files. In a low-traffic web, 1% is fine.